# rvalue references in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, rvalue-reference

What are the differences between rvalue references as implemented in Visual Studio 2010 and as specified in the C++11? Are there any particular pitfalls to watch out for when using revalue references in Visual Studio 2010 that could make source invalid or working differently if compiled by C++11 conforming compiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this table](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx), VS2010 supports rvalue references version 2.0 (the current version is 2.1 IIRC).

The important difference between 2.0 and 2.1 is that the latter allows implicit conversions:

```
std::string&& x = "hello";   // legal in 2.1, illegal in 2.0
```

Also note that VS2010 does not yet support overloading on the rvalueness of `*this`.

```
void Foo::foo() && { ... }   // not yet supported in VS2010
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the instalment number 9 of [Stephan T. Lavavej](http://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/stephan-t-lavavej)'s video lectures at [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/tags/C9+Lectures) from **42:30 min** onwards. He explains timeline and evolution of the *rvalue references and move semantic* in Visual Studio.

Here it is: [C9 Lectures: Stephan T. Lavavej - Standard Template Library (STL), 9 of n](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-9-of-n)